# Odd Getopt (1) parsing behavior

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, getopt

Using getopt (1) for parsing some options in bash and it is not evaluating when i pass it options from the cmd line. It is defaulting to the --) "double dash" case statement and passing the other options when i supply them, not sure why it is causing this odd behavior, code below:

```
parse_args() {
    cmd=""              # Default none
    isparsed=0          # If args parsed = 1

    # Check the number of arguments. If none are passed, print help and exit
    options=$(getopt -o hs:d:c:p:i: -l help,source:,destination:,connection:,platform:,install: -n "cdr" -- "$@")

    # If the number of arguments after processing them using getopt is larger 
    # than zero, then it means there is an unknown argument.
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        HELP
        exit 1
    fi

    printdbg "parsing options"
    eval set -- "$options"
    while true; do
        case "$1" in
            -h) # Show help option menu
                HELP
                exit 1
                ;;
            -s|--source) # Parse options to source sub command
                cmd=$2 # Remove 'source' from the argument list
                shift;
                if [[ $cmd == "sqlite" ]]; then
                    SOURCE="sqlite"
                elif [[ $cmd == "mysql" ]]; then
                    SOURCE="mysql"
                else
                    HELP
                    exit 1
                fi
                isparsed=1
                ;;
            -d|--destination) # Parse options to destination sub command
                cmd=$2 # Remove 'destination' from the argument list
                shift;
                if [[ $cmd == "postgre" ]]; then
                    DESTINATION="postgre"
                elif [[ $cmd == "riak" ]]; then
                    DESTINATION="riak"
                elif [[ $cmd == "both" ]]; then
                    DESTINATION="both"
                else
                    HELP
                    exit 1
                fi
                isparsed=1
                ;;
            -c|--connection) # Parse options to connection sub command
                cmd=$2 # Remove 'connection' from the argument list
                shift; printdbg "$cmd"
                if [[ ! -z $cmd ]]; then
                    SOURCE_CONN=$(echo "$cmd" | awk -F "::" '{print $1}')
                    DESTINATION_CONN=$(echo "$cmd" | awk -F "::" '{print $2}')
                    parse_csv "$SOURCE_CONN"  #stored in PARSED_ARR
                    echo ${PARSED_ARR[@]}
#                    ${DESTINATION_CONN:=${PARSED_ARR}}
                else
                    HELP
                    exit 1
                fi
                isparsed=1
                ;;
            -p|--platform) # Parse options to platform sub command
                cmd=$2 # Remove 'platform' from the argument list
                shift;
                if [[ $cmd == "csv" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=1
                elif [[ $cmd == "api" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=2
                elif [[ $cmd == "freeswitch" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=3
                elif [[ $cmd == "asterisk" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=4
                elif [[ $cmd == "yate" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=5
                elif [[ $cmd == "kamailio" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=6
                elif [[ $cmd == "opensips" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=7
                elif [[ $cmd == "sipwise" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=8
                elif [[ $cmd == "veraz" ]]; then
                    CDR_TYPE=9
                else
                    HELP
                    exit 1
                fi
                isparsed=1
                ;;
            -i|--install) # Parse options to install sub command
                cmd=$2 # Remove 'install' from the argument list
                shift;
                if [[ $cmd == "sqlite" ]]; then
                    install_dependencies
                    install_sqlite
                elif [[ $cmd == "mysql" ]]; then
                    install_dependencies
                    install_mysql
                elif [[ $cmd == "postgre" ]]; then
                    install_dependencies
                    install_postgre
                elif [[ $cmd == "riak" ]]; then
                    printwarn "This feature will be supported in future versions"
                    exit 1
                elif [[ $cmd == "pusher" ]]; then
                    install_dependencies
                    install_golang
                    install_cdrpusher
                    install_supervisord
                elif [[ $cmd == "stats" ]]; then
                    install_dependencies
                    install_golang
                    install_cdrstats
                else
                    HELP
                    exit 1
                fi
                isparsed=1
                ;;
            --) 
                shift
                break
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

I can tell it is defaulting to that point in the case statement because the isparsed flag is still not set ( == 0 ) and i print the error to the console from my main()

```
main() {
    . cdr_funcs
    check_permissions
    detect_os
    parse_args

    if [[ ${isparsed} == 1 ]]; then
        INSTALL_COMPLETE_MESG
        exit 0
    fi

    printerr "isparsed flag == 0"
    HELP
    exit 1
}
```

Running with an -h flag shows this blatantly:

```
devbox cdr # ./cdr -h
[DEBUG] [check_permissions]: Root Permissions Validated
[DEBUG] [detect_os]: Starting OS Platform detection
[DEBUG] [detect_os]: Checking OS Compatibility
[DEBUG] [detect_os]: OS detected: [linux] (OS is supported)
[DEBUG] [detect_os]: Finished OS detection
[DEBUG] [parse_args]: parsing options
[ERROR] [main]: isparsed flag == 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a function (`parse_args`), `"$@"` expands to the arguments from the invocation of the function, not the enclosing script. There aren't any, so `getopt` sees no arguments, and produces no options.

If you want to analyse the script arguments with a function, you need to provide them to the function:

```
parse_args "$@"
```